# Error in Chapter 15 (Mechanical Waves) of University Physics with Modern Physics - 13th Edition?

Tags: waves

After reading [this question](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/64026/error-in-sears-and-zemanskys-university-physics-with-modern-physics-13th-editi) I figured someone here would be able to answer this as well:

I thought the answer to part (c) of this question:

[image: University Physics with Modern Physics (13thE) - pg 482]

(Figure 15.8 to the right:)

[image: University Physics with Modern Physics (13thE) - pg 477]

was

$$\frac{3}{8}T$$

but in page 508 it's written:

[image: University Physics with Modern Physics (13thE) - pg 508]

I can see the particle at C has a downward acceleration at $t=\frac{5}{8}T$, but does it have an **upward velocity**?

Thanks in advance for the attention.

Answer (score 1):

You are right. It is a mistake in the book. Everything is just as you said.